# TCP/IP - Why does a part of a packet may use a connection-less services in a connection-oriented service.

Tags: networking, tcp

While reading the book on TCP/IP I came across the words which are as "Although it looks as though the use of the flow label may make the source and destination addresses useless, the parts of the Internet that use connection-less service at the network layer still keep these addresses for several reasons.One reason is that part of the packet path may still be using the connection-less service. Another reason is that the protocol at the network layer is designed with these addresses and it may take a while before they can be changed". Now my question to you is if a connection has been formed between hosts in a connection-oriented manner then how come a path of a packet may still be using the connection-less services. Because as per my knowledge prevails the virtual path always be formed at while 3-way handshake is taking place which is the TCP/IP connection (which uses a connection-oriented service) ? And my second question for the second reason is that which protocol they are talking about since these words are stated below the Heading of "Connection-Oriented Services" therefore, it's making me pissed off to understand the literal meaning behind the words(The core conceptual understanding). And correct if anyone thinks I am having a wrong concept at any place. I'll be obliged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TCP as a connection-oriented protocol runs on top of IP which is connection-less. The routers used in transport only look at the IP packet, the TCP segment is simply payload and transported along. TCP provides several algorithms to form a *virtual* connection over a connection-less network.

The IP packet goes from hop to hop. On each hop, a router makes a forwarding decision solely based on the destination IP address. (More sophisticated devices may inspect more packet elements including source address and payload, but they aren't simple routers.)

The "path" is made up of all these individual hops. Because each hop is based on an independent routing decision the path can change at any time and for any packet. The path is *not* laid out by the TCP handshake.

Basically, you have to look at each protocol layer individually. Each one serves its own function.

I hope this also answers the second question.

Comment: Sir but if each hop (which is router) decides to route the packet  to the destination or in order words if each hop is independent to make a decision on how to route an incoming packet then why the books are writing the point that in connection-oriented service a virtual path is formed/decided and the packet are restricted to take that path only?

Comment: The path is only virtually formed. No packet is restricted to a specific path. It's up to the routers to decide that, one hop at a time. Likely, the decisions will be the same for each packet but not necessarily so.

Comment: Oh! you saved my day. Thanks a'lot.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it resolves your question.